# Angular - ngx-Pagination not working as expected

Tags: angular, pagination, ngx-bootstrap

In Angular-14, I am implementing server-side pagination using `ngx-bootstrap-pagination` with ASP.NET Core-6 as the backend.

service:

```
getPaymentStatus(): Observable<IPaymentStatus[]> {
  return this.http.get<IPaymentStatus[]>(this.baseUrl + '/payments-status');
}
```

I got this JSON response from the backend:

```
{
    "data": {
        "pageItems": [
            {
                "id": "2b0ab0db-523f-4b5f-837e-3f24ba6e0325",
                "dueDate": "2025-06-12T00:00:00",
                "narration": null,
                "paymentStatus": 0
            },
            ....
        ],
        "pageSize": 10,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "numberOfPages": 9,
        "totalRecord": 81
    },
    "successful": true,
    "message": "All data retrieved successfully",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

So, in the typescipt, I got this:

component.ts:

```
  page: number = 1;
  pageSize!: number;
  currentPage!: number;
  numberOfPages!: number;
  totalRecords!: number;
  pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllPayments();
  }

  getRequestParams(page: number, pageSize: number): any {
    let params: any = {};
    if (page) {
      params[`page`] = page - 1;
    }
    if (pageSize) {
      params[`size`] = pageSize;
    }
    return params;
  }

  handlePageChange(event: number): void {
    this.page = event;
    this.loadAllPayments();
  }

  handlePageSizeChange(event: any): void {
    this.pageSize = event.target.value;
    this.page = 1;
    this.loadAllPayments();
  }

  onTableDataChange(event: any) {
    this.currentPage = event;
    this.loadAllPayments();
  }
  onTableSizeChange(event: any): void {
    this.pageSize = event.target.value;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.loadAllPayments();
  }

  loadAllPayments() {
    this.dataService.getPaymentStatus().subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.allPaymentList = res.data.pageItems;
        this.totalRecords = res.data.totalRecord;
        this.currentPage = res.data.currentPage;
        this.pageSize = res.data.pageSize;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.toastr.error(error.message);
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    })
  }
```

component.html:

```
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
              <th>Due Date</th>
              <th>Narration</th>
              <th>Payment Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody *ngIf="allPaymentList != undefined">
            <tr *ngFor="let row of allPaymentList
            | paginate : {
              itemsPerPage: pageSize,
              currentPage: currentPage,
              totalItems: totalRecords
            }; let i = index;">
              <td>{{ i + 1 }}.</td>
              <td>{{ row?.dueDate | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy' || 'N/A' }}</td>
              <td>{{ row?.narration || 'N/A' }}</td>
              <td>{{ row?.paymentStatus || 'N/A' }}</td>
              <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="viewPaymentData(paymentDetail, row)">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> View
                </a>&nbsp;
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="allPaymentList.length ==0;">
              <td colspan="9" class="text-center">
                <span class="align-center">No Data Found!</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer clearfix">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <pagination-controls
            previousLabel="Prev"
            nextLabel="Next"
            [responsive]="true"
            (pageChange)="onTableDataChange($event)"
          >
          </pagination-controls>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Items Per Page:
            <select (change)="onTableSizeChange($event)">
              <option *ngFor="let size of pageSizes" [ngValue]="size">
                {{ size }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

console.log(this.allPaymentList) gives:

```
{
    "data": {
        "pageItems": [
            {
                "id": "2b0ab0db-523f-4b5f-837e-3f24ba6e0325",
                "dueDate": "2025-06-12T00:00:00",
                "narration": null,
                "paymentStatus": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "d76b297a-70b5-4a29-82e1-937f6710cbb2",
                "dueDate": "2025-03-12T00:00:00",
                "narration": null,
                "paymentStatus": 0
            },
            {
                "id": "ef94ac6e-e18e-474f-961b-3b995ce7b4a7",
                "dueDate": "2024-12-12T00:00:00",
                "narration": null,
                "paymentStatus": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": "a4b35e3b-0bb7-4115-aee7-858259703b62",
                "dueDate": "2023-03-12T00:00:00",
                "narration": null,
                "paymentStatus": 0
            }
             ...
        ],
        "pageSize": 10,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "numberOfPages": 9,
        "totalRecord": 81,
        "previousPage": 0
    },
    "successful": true,
    "message": "All payments retrieved successfully",
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

The pagination is as shown below:

[image: pagination]

which is correct.

But where I have an issue is that when I click on each number (1,2,3,4 ..9), it remains on the same page instead of navigating to the next page.
Also, the Item Per Page is not taking me to the pages.

How do I correct all these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to tell the API to return the correct data based on your pagination input format.

Here is what you can do.

in you service you need to add more information to send (this data must be provided by your backend team.

So, from this

```js
getPaymentStatus(): Observable<IPaymentStatus[]> {
  return this.http.get<IPaymentStatus[]>(this.baseUrl + '/payments-status');
}
```

Change it to:

```js
getPaymentStatus(page: number = 1, perPage: number = 10): Observable<IPaymentStatus[]> {
  return this.http.get<IPaymentStatus[]>(this.baseUrl + `/payments-status?page=${page}&perPage=${perPage}`);
}
```

Note: Keys `page` and `perPage` must be provided by your backend team.

---

Now, in your components you can make a request with more inputs `this.dataService.getPaymentStatus($page, $perPage)`

Like:

```js
// Example One: page 1, 10 per page
this.dataService.getPaymentStatus(1).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log({data});
});


// Example Two: page 2, 20 per page
this.dataService.getPaymentStatus(2, 20).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log({data});
});
```

And so on...

Comment: That has already been taken care of from the backend. See console.log(this.allPaymentList) towards the end of my submitted and updated code. It displays totalPages and perPage. But the issue as I stated is that clicking on each number (1,2,3, ...9) is not going to its page and also ItemPerPage is not responding. That's why I put the screenshot

Comment: I know, but you are only changing the local variables, when you press on page 2, the local variable will change, that's true, and you will fetch the same data for page 1. But, If you provided a query params in the URL when making a request, It will tell the API which page you want to retrieve.

Comment: Is currentPage in the API JSON response not the same as $page that you gave. Secondly, can you repoduce the solution in stackblitz. .Thanks